# updating and than commiting to svn with java code

Tags: java, svn

*Hi All
i just started using SVNkit and tried using its features.
i wanted to take update first of particular directory and than commit it into the svn .
But i am facing problems .
code for taking update

```
public class TestSVNConnection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DAVRepositoryFactory.setup();    
        FSRepositoryFactory.setup();
                SVNRepositoryFactoryImpl.setup();
        //This is a general way how to creates an SVNRepository driver object:
        File dstPath = new File("C:/Users/Testcases/NEWFrameWork/src/de/eb/test/generic/destinationentry/");
        String url = "http://subversion/svn/navi/TestTools/work/somu8950/NEWFrameWork/src/de/eb/test/generic/destinationentry";
        String username = "username";
        String password= "password";        
        SVNRepository repository = null;
        ISVNAuthenticationManager authManager=null;

        try {
            repository = SVNRepositoryFactory.create(SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url));
            ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
            authManager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager(username, password);
            repository.setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
            //output some data to verify connection
            System.out.println("Repository Root: " + repository.getRepositoryRoot(true));
            System.out.println("Repository UUID: " + repository.getRepositoryUUID(true));
            //need to identify latest revision
            long latestRevision = repository.getLatestRevision();
            System.out.println("Repository Latest Revision: " + latestRevision);
            //create client manager and set authentication
            SVNClientManager cm = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options,authManager);


            //use SVNUpdateClient to do the update
            SVNUpdateClient uc = cm.getUpdateClient();
            long[] l =  uc.doUpdate(new File[]{dstPath}, SVNRevision.HEAD,SVNDepth.INFINITY, true,true);
           System.out.println("update is done ....  :) :)" +l[0]);*

}
```

but here i am getting error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.antlr.runtime.RecognitionException 
at line  :
    long[] l =  uc.doUpdate(new File[]{dstPath}, SVNRevision.HEAD,SVNDepth.INFINITY, true,true);
           System.out.println("update is done ....  :) :)" +l[0]);*
```

Even i have prepared the code for Commit 
its also not working .

please someone help me on this or share a piece of code .

Thanks In Advance .

Comment: If you're getting a `ClassNotFoundException` on the class `org.antlr.runtime.RecognigitionException` it means that you're not referencing all the class jars that are in `lib/` of the svnkit package - one of which is `antlr-runtime-3.4.jar`

Comment: could you please share the code for commiting the directory or file.i have used SVNCommitInfo impInfo = commitClient.doImport(fileToCheckin,SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(url) ,"Done changes for the new req",null,true,true,SVNDepth.INFINITY); but its failing .